# Play live audio source with discord.py

Tags: python, audio, discord.py

I would like to create a bot command that joins a Discord voice channel and plays an audio source from a twitch url (www.twitch.tv/).
If I'm not wrong I would need :
-firstly, get this audio source,
-secondly, transform it into an audio flux
-then, play it to the channel.

I'm really novice to audio in python and don't know what to do for the two first steps.
The code I have right now is this :

```
@commands.command(aliases=['playstream'])
    async def play_stream(self, ctx):
        self.vc = await self.bot.stream_chan.connect()
        self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('testing.mp3'), after=lambda e: print('done', e))
        self.vc.is_playing()
```

discord.py accept different format ([url to documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AudioSource)) but don't know what lib I must use to get the twitch audio and then transform it if necessary.

Could you help me to get this ?
Thx for reading

**Edit :** youtube_dl should work for twitch but I don't find any doc/example

Comment: As far as I know youtube_dl doesn't connect to twitch and you cant play live audio source from it.